# Is there a StyleCop-like plug-in for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to program in Java and would like something that works like StyleCop in Visual Studio.

Does anyone know about something like that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use the [eclipse-cs Checkstyle plug-in](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/). There are other tools, such as [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), but I think Checkstyle is the easiest and fastest. And of course, you can configure Eclipse to be less lenient.